# What is this flying debris during Ariane 5 liftoff

Tags: ariane

Trigger warning: jaw-dropping picture
[image]

Source: (Warning, more pictures) [Ars Technica](https://arstechnica.com/science/2019/12/an-ariane-rocket-launches-for-the-250th-time-the-views-were-jawdropping/)
Credits: ESA/Trevor Mahlmann
Launch: [VA250](https://www.arianespace.com/press-release/arianes-250th-mission-is-a-success-tiba-1-and-inmarsat-gx5-are-in-orbit/)

Comment: That is indeed a fine picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a cover plate at the top of the Etage d'Acceleration à Poudre (EAP) – solid rocket booster at the nose cone that at the time of launch comes off exposing the separation rockets.

[image: EAP Solid Rocket Booster Infographic]

**Video of Covers coming off**

This slow motion video of the [Ariane V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5) launch shows the plates coming off a few seconds after ignition. In the video, they fall away at 41 second mark.

More information:

- https://www.arianespace.com/vehicle/ariane-5/
- https://www.esa.int/Enabling_Support/Space_Transportation/Launch_vehicles/Boosters_EAP

[image: Ariane 5 Rocket]

Comment: What does EAP stand for?

Comment: It's "Etage d'Acceleration à Poudre", French for Solid Rocket Booster. I added that to my answer. I could not figure out what it meant and had to search further.

Comment: Thanks, this and your edit makes it much clearer, +1

Comment: What is their purpose ?

Comment: @OrganicMarble FYI, https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/why-strap-on-boosters-and-how-do-other-people-say-it/36251

Comment: Their purpose is to prevent frost forming on the front attachment points. They're blocks of insulation foam.