# What's the shiny silver turnip on the bottom of this Ariane 5 launcher?

Tags: identify-this-object, ariane

The beautiful cutaway drawing included in this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40216/6944) shows a metallic turnip-shaped object attached to the bottom of the Ariane V core stage.

What is that object?

[image]

Comment: It's the Chemtrail generator obviously.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's an Helium tank; nicknamed *LHESS*

This website [capcomespace.net](http://www.capcomespace.net/dossiers/espace_europeen/ariane/ariane5/moteur_vulcain.htm) have a very good article on the subject (in french)

Extract (roughly translated):

> The tanks pressurisation system preserve the tanks structural integrity, and a continuous propellant flow. The LOX tank is pressurised by 141kg of liquid helium stored at 7°K and 19 bar, warmed up by contact with the turbine exhaust. The flow is 0,2 kg-s, regulated by vanes on a rotatory disc.  The H2 tank pressurisation is done with gaseous H2.

Some illustrations: 
[image]

- 6 is labelled "6/ Sphère de pressurisation réservoir LOX (145 kg d' hélium)" => Helium for LOX tank pressurisation (145kg)

Also seen on this schematic with a similar label:[image]
*color legend: In light blue, the pressurisation line running up to the LOX tank, dark blue is the Liquid Helium tank. Green are He tank too, but used for the gimbal system*

[image]

AirLiquide, the tank maker has a product page describing it [here](https://advancedtech.airliquide.com/liquid-helium-tanks)

Extract:

> Proven experience ǀ LHESS supercritical helium tanks have been fitted on Ariane 5 since its first launch in 1996, thereby proving their efficiency and robustness. Moreover, they have been continuously improved to increase their performance

Comment: I love the schematic drawing! Thanks. You also explained what pressurized the hydrogen tank which I was curious about.

Comment: @OrganicMarble added a short translation of the color code to highlight the He line

Comment: Literal translation: *"LOX reservoir pressurisation sphere (145 kg of helium)"*